# Writing a loop to read_html through a column of url's

Tags: r, rvest

I am using `rvest` to scrape some corporate documents from the US Securities and Exchange Commission. Starting with a specific company, I successfully extracted the URL's to each of their 10k documents and put those URL's in a data frame named xcel. I then would like to further scrape each of those URL's.

I am thinking it makes the most sense to use a for loop to go through each of the URL's in the `xcel$fullurl` column, use the `read_html` function on each of them, and extract the table on each page).

I am having trouble getting the actual for loop to work. If you think a for loop is not the way to go, I would love to hear any other advice.

```
library(rvest)
library(stringi)

sec<-read_html("https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar? 
action=getcompany&CIK=0000072903&type=10-k&dateb=&owner=exclude&count=40")
xcel<- sec %>%
 html_nodes("#documentsbutton") %>%
 html_attr("href")
xcel<-data.frame(xcel)
xcel$xcell<-paste0("https://www.sec.gov",xcel$xcell)
xcel$fullurl<-paste0(xcel$xcell,xcel$xcel)
as.character(xcel$fullurl)      #set of URL's that I want to scrape from

#Problem starts here

for (i in xcel$fullurl){
  pageurl<-xcel$fullurl
  phase2 <- read_html(pageurl[i])

hopefully<-phase2 %>%
   html_table("tbody")
```

hopefully     this should give me the ensuing table from each of the 
     sites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could loop over each URL using `map`/`lapply` and extract the 1st table from each

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

map(xcel$fullurl, ~ .x %>% read_html() %>%  html_table() %>% .[[1]])

#   Seq                   Description                   Document     Type     Size
#1    1                          10-K       xcel1231201510-k.htm     10-K  6375358
#2    2                 EXHIBIT 10.28       xcelex1028q42015.htm EX-10.28    57583
#3    3                 EXHIBIT 10.29       xcelex1029q42015.htm EX-10.29    25233
#4    4                 EXHIBIT 12.01       xcelex1201q42015.htm EX-12.01    50108
#5    5                 EXHIBIT 21.01       xcelex2101q42015.htm EX-21.01    22841
#.....
```

This would return a list of dataframes. If you want to combine all of them into a single dataframe you could use `map_dfr` instead of `map`.

Comment: Thank you! This solution worked perfectly and after reading through the Map function more, I think I will be able to use it for more of the work here going forward as well.